# MongoDB Roles - user access multiple databases

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I would like to give acces to a user to 2 databases in MongoDB.

I tried this, but it only give access to the admin db.

```
use admin;
db.runCommand(
{
    createUser: "myuser",
    pwd : "mypwd",
    roles: 
    [
        { role: "readWrite", db: "db1" } ,
        { role: "readWrite", db: "db2" } 
    ]
});
```

I tried to create the user on each db, but i end up with 2 users:
`user@db1` and `user@db2`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Users can basically be saved in *any* database, which is why you can provide **[`--authenticationDatabase`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongotop/#cmdoption--authenticationDatabase)** on the command line tools, for example.

Taking the example for the cli, your command line should look something like this

```
mongo yourhost:yourport/db1 -u myuser --authenticationDatabase admin -p
```

and

```
mongo yourhost:yourport/db2 -u myuser --authenticationDatabase admin -p
```

respectively, where you obvisouly have to substitute **`yourhost`** and **`yourport`** for actual values.